# My NavBar is not appearing in Mobile View?

Tags: html, mobile, navbar

```
<header role="banner">
    <div style="background-color: #1A2B57;">
        <img src="~/images/logo_sm.png" width="280" height="60" style="width: 15%;margin:0 auto;margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom:15px;margin-left: 194px;" alt="logo" />
        <nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" role="navigation" style="float:right;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:white;width: 80%;margin:0 auto;">
        <nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a class="nav-link" asp-area="Index" asp-controller="EnrollmentForm" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-left:50%;">
                        <li class="active"><a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="" asp-action="">Hello @(User.Identity.Name)</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Authentication" asp-action="Logout" class="navbar-nav nav-link-1 btn btn-primary">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <hr />
    </div>
</header><!-- header role="banner" -->
```

I can't figure out why my navbar doesn't appear when the screen width is less than 992 pixels.

Here are the javascript libraries I am using

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/DataTables/datatables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/js/z-validations.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```